# Map issues in adding key-value pairs

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Check the below lines :

```
Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>;
map.put("a",a);
map.put("b",b);
map.put("c",c);
```

Note : All the 3 variables do have values.

I am creating a map and adding 3 key-value pairs in it.
But on inspecting the object, its size is 3 but the values added in the HashMap are always only a and b.

Any idea of the solution or cause of the problem?

Comment: which language is this? Java? - if so, add a tag.

Comment: How do you know that there are ever only 2 values added?

Comment: @Kith - I am debugging the code. While inspecting the object map, its showing size=3 but only 2 of the values are actually getting added in the map object.

Comment: @DavieBrown - Yes, it is. No idea about tag. Explain please.

Comment: similarly to how you added the tag for "map" - just so it makes it easier for people to locate specific categories of questions. If you edit the question you should be able to add to the Tags section.

Comment: @DavieBrown - aaahhhh...question tags..!! Done.

Comment: Just to rule it out: When are you inspecting the object? (If the final line is highlighted when paused, inspecting `map` will only show two elements as the highlighting indicates what's ABOUT to be executed, not what was JUST executed.)

Comment: @Smallhacker - I do know that. I am checking the object when the last line(adding c object) has been executed and flow is coming to the next line.

Comment: add System.out.println(map.size()); the code looks fine if your vars are initialized correctly. Show that code.

Comment: Have you verified that `c` actually has a value? Have you verified that it is associated correctly with the `"c"` key when put in the map?

Comment: C do have the value, and map.size is giving 3 as the value.

Comment: Maybe c fell into the same bin as another key. Have you tried retrieving "c" from the hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

Check your complete program again. It should work.

```
public class Main3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("a",new String("abc"));
        map.put("b",new String("pqr"));
        map.put("c",new String("xyz"));

        Iterator<?> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        } 
    }
}
```

==================================================================================

a = abc

c = xyz

b = pqr